# C++ cout function print

Tags: c++, cout

Why this function:

```
uint64_t rot_xor(uint64_t a1, uint64_t a2) {
    int size = sizeof(a1)*4;
    cout<<" "<<"size:"<<bitset<8>(size).to_string()<<" "<<size;
    int shift;
    uint64_t output = 0;
    cout<<endl;
    for (shift = 0; shift < size; shift++)
        if(a1&(1<<shift)) {
            output ^= (a2 << shift) | (a2 >> (size - shift));
            cout << bitset<64>(output).to_string()<<endl;
        }
return output;
}
```

Print output:

---

1. : size:00010000 20
2. : 0000000000000000000000000000000010110000110000011111001011111001

Comment: Why would it not? What were you expecting it to print and what are you passing in to it?

Comment: you can see there http://ideone.com/zkqMPO

Comment: int size = sizeof(a1);
    cout<<endl<<"size:"<<bitset<8>(size).to_string()<<" "<<size;
    size=size*4;
    cout<<" "<<"size:"<<bitset<8>(size).to_string()<<" "<<size;
Print: size:00001000 8 size:00100000 20

Comment: @AgentIvan: Please look at your previous comment.  Is the code readable?  Please **edit** your question/post with code, so it is more readable.

Comment: What are you expecting this function to do?  What is the expected behavior?

Comment: What a1 and a2 input produces the output of your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**point 1**

If the question is why your program prints 20 as a result of what seems to be `sizeof(uint64_t) * 4` instead of 32, well it's because a few lines before calling `rot_xor` there is a:

```
cout << hex
```

In fact, the exact output as can be seen in the link you posted is

```
size:00100000 20
```

or 32 in binary and hexadecimal representation.

**point 2**

I have no idea what your expected ouput should be like.